# Prove formulae using natural style

Tags: proof-writing

> Prove: $((P ⇒ R) ∧ (Q ⇒ R)) ⇔ ((P ∨ Q) ⇒ R)$
>
> Notation: $P[x]$ and $f[x$] for “$P$ applied to $x$” and “$f$ applied to $x$”, instead of $P(x)$ and $f(x)$.

So far I tried the following:

**Direction $=>$**

- Assume ( (P => R)^ (Q => R) ) (1) and Prove ( (P v Q)=> R )
- From (1) we get (P => R)(2) and (Q => R)(3)
- From (2) we get P (4)  From (3) we get Q (5)

**Direction $<=$**

- Assume ( (P v Q) => R ) (6) and Prove ( (P => R) ^ (Q => R) )
- From (6) by material implication we get ~(P v Q) v R (7)
- We can rewrite (7) as (~P ^ ~Q) v R (8) by negation rules
- We can retwrite (8) as (~P v R) ^ (~Q v R) (9) by distributivity laws
- We can rewrite (9) as (P => R ) ^ (Q => R) by material implication.

> I got stuck solving first direction $=>$. What should I do next?
>
> Regarding the other direction $<=$, is there any other way to do it without rewriting?

Thanks.